# Pandas converts list of datetime values incorrectly

Tags: datetime, pandas

I have a list of datetime values, and would like to convert the list into a pandas.Series instance. The code boils down to the following:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil import parser

day = parser.parse('2016-08-07T00:00:00Z')
dates = [day + timedelta(days=delta) for delta in range(80)]

pandas.Series(dates)
```

What puzzles me is that the code above returned lots of datetime instance of 1970-01-01:

```
0    2016-08-07 00:00:00+00:00
1    1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
2    1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
3    1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
4    1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
5    1970-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
...
```

However, if I convert any sublist of 60 elements or fewer, I can get back a correct series:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil import parser

day = parser.parse('2016-08-07T00:00:00Z')
dates = [day + timedelta(days=delta) for delta in range(80)]

pandas.Series(dates[0:60])
```

Note the last line, the input of pandas.Series becomes dates[0:60]. In fact, it can be any dates[n:n+60], where n is between 0 and len(dates) - 60.

```
0    2016-08-07 00:00:00+00:00
1    2016-08-08 00:00:00+00:00 
2    2016-08-09 00:00:00+00:00
3    2016-08-10 00:00:00+00:00
4    2016-08-11 00:00:00+00:00
5    2016-08-12 00:00:00+00:00
...
```

I also read the Pandas document on Series and datetime, and tried Pandas' timestamp, but still go the the same result. The Pandas version is 0.18.1, and the Python version used by the iPython notebook kernel is 2.7.3:

```
print  pandas.__version__

import sys
print(sys.version)
```

The output is

```
0.18.1
2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
```

Any hints on what I should look into to find out why this problem happens and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue using pandas 0.18.1 in conjunction with Python (3.5.1 or 2.7.11)

Comment: @MaxU Strange. My pandas is 0.18.1 and the Python version is 2.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's wrong with your Python version, but you can and should use vectorized (i.e. much more efficient and faster) pandas methods instead of vanilla Python methods:

```
In [181]: pd.Series([pd.to_datetime('2016-08-07T00:00:00Z') + pd.Timedelta(days=delta) for delta in range(80)])
Out[181]:
0    2016-08-07
1    2016-08-08
2    2016-08-09
3    2016-08-10
4    2016-08-11
5    2016-08-12
6    2016-08-13
7    2016-08-14
8    2016-08-15
9    2016-08-16
10   2016-08-17
11   2016-08-18
12   2016-08-19
13   2016-08-20
14   2016-08-21
15   2016-08-22
16   2016-08-23
17   2016-08-24
18   2016-08-25
19   2016-08-26
20   2016-08-27
21   2016-08-28
22   2016-08-29
23   2016-08-30
24   2016-08-31
25   2016-09-01
26   2016-09-02
27   2016-09-03
28   2016-09-04
29   2016-09-05
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has the utility function `pd.date_range` to generate this kind of objects:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(pd.date_range(start='2016-08-07T00:00:00Z', periods=80, freq='D'))
```

Output:

```
0    2016-08-07 00:00:00+00:00
1    2016-08-08 00:00:00+00:00
2    2016-08-09 00:00:00+00:00
3    2016-08-10 00:00:00+00:00
4    2016-08-11 00:00:00+00:00
5    2016-08-12 00:00:00+00:00
6    2016-08-13 00:00:00+00:00
7    2016-08-14 00:00:00+00:00
8    2016-08-15 00:00:00+00:00
9    2016-08-16 00:00:00+00:00
                ...           
70   2016-10-16 00:00:00+00:00
71   2016-10-17 00:00:00+00:00
72   2016-10-18 00:00:00+00:00
73   2016-10-19 00:00:00+00:00
74   2016-10-20 00:00:00+00:00
75   2016-10-21 00:00:00+00:00
76   2016-10-22 00:00:00+00:00
77   2016-10-23 00:00:00+00:00
78   2016-10-24 00:00:00+00:00
79   2016-10-25 00:00:00+00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```